# Adding different UITapGestureRecognizer to UIViews

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I've made a custom `UIView` that appears in my app in two places. It first appears in a regular view controller along with a `text view`, and then a tap gesture on the `UIView` moves to another `view controller` where the `custom UIView` is shown enlarged. I want to have a different tap gesture for the enlarged `UIView`, but when I tried putting this into the `storyboard`, the first tap gesture stopped working (since the new tap gesture was only reachable via the first tap gesture's segue to the new view controller, I wasn't able to see if it worked or not.

Does adding the second `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view cause the first to become invalid? I don't see any other reason this would've caused an issue. If so, do I need to create separate classes for the two different custom UIViews? I tried to avoid this since they're showing the same thing just in different sizes but it seems the different tap gestures may be causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding different `UITapGesture` in different.

**View1**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapBehind1:)];
[recognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; 
[View1 addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

**View2**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapBehind2:)];
[recognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; 
[View2 addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

**View1 handle Tap method**

```
- (void)handleTapBehind:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
     {

          [View1 removeGestureRecognizer:sender];

     }
}
```

**View2 handle Tap method**

```
- (void)handleTapBehind:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
     {

          [View2 removeGestureRecognizer:sender];

     }
}
```

Comment: so these do need to be in separate view classes then?

Comment: do these need to be in the viewDidLoad method of the corresponding superview controllers?